Are $\mu_{\hat{p}}$ and $\sigma_{\hat{p}}$ considered parameters or statistics?
Is $\mu_{\hat{p}}$ (the mean of the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$) and $\sigma_{\hat{p}}$ (the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$) considered parameters or statistics, where $\hat{p}$ is the sample proportion?
I have the following definitions: 
Parameter - a number that describes the entire population. 
Statistic - a number that describes a sample.
I consider them to be statistics because they describe $\hat{p}$ which is a statistic - their values are based on the sample proportion and the sample size. Is this way of thinking incorrect?

There are a variety of definitions of both, but for me a "parameter" is a value that underpins the behaviour of some random variable, while a "statistic" is a value calculated from sample values.
In that sense, $\mu_\hat{p}$ and $\sigma_\hat{p}$ are both parameters that describe the distribution of $\hat{p}$. I could then construct estimators of both, $\hat{\mu}_\hat{p}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_\hat{p}$ that I could then calculate using sample data, and those estimators would be statistics.

Moments of a (parametric) distribution are parameters.  That's why they are called parametric distributions.  That the distribution is a sampling distribution is immaterial.
For instance, if we have the sampling distribution of the sample mean, i.e., the distribution of $\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i$ are iid following some distribution with mean $\mu$, then the expectation of $\bar X$ is also $\mu$.  It doesn't change from sample to sample.
It's worth mentioning that the phrase "sampling distribution" does not uniquely specify the nature of the statistic calculated from the sample.  For instance, for a sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, one may construct many familiar statistics:  the sample mean $\bar X$ as described above, but also the sample minimum $X_{(1)}$, the sample range $X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$, the sample median, the sample standard deviation $s$, etc.
But in any case, the sampling distribution of any statistic will have moments that are functions of the parameters of the distribution from which observations are realized.  Therefore, the mean and standard deviation of the sampling distributions of such statistics are parameters, not statistics themselves.
